# How to receive packets sent by iOT devices over TCP protocol?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, tcp, iot, aws-nlb

I'm designing a solution where +7000 IoT devices (Teltonika Trackers) are sending packets over TCP protocol every 15 minutes. Whenever a packet comes, I want to pass it to Lambda function for parsing/processing.

Please note that the trackers must be configured with a static IP address which will send packets to.

I can think of NLB -> ALB -> Lambda or simply an EC2 with enhanced networking running a small script for intercepting. Is there a better approach ?

[EDIT]
Since the devices can only establish raw TCP connections, using Load Balancers have no use. However, I came across an article explaining how to assign a static IP address for Lambda function.
https://digitalvarys.com/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-to-the-aws-lambda-function/
Based on that, can I configure an Elastic Network Interface for the Lambda function with a static IP and add a security group to the ENI specifying a port enabling Lambda to receive TCP packets ?

Comment: If you're designing/building the solution I would review using soem of the https://aws.amazon.com/iot/ services and thinking about what/how you push data from the IoT devices to AWS.  In my opinion there is little value in re-inventing what already exists...

Comment: I can't use IoT core because it doesn't support TCP, only MQTT.